# zsh sleep assistance with loop

Tags: loops, unix, curl, zsh

Very simple request: have a 1 second pause between each curl post

```
#!/usr/local/bin/zsh
while true
do
 for p (**/*.xml) {curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/xml"  -d @"${p}" "https://url/postAPI" > "post_${p}"}
     sleep 1
 done
```

The sleep DOES pause but in increments of 3.

What am I doing wrong??

Thanks!

When I say increments, thisis what I mean.

```
post
post
post
sleep 1
```

and I would like:

```
post
sleep 1
post
sleep 1
post
sleep 1
```

In this tmp directory, there are only three files but eventually they'll be 300.

Comment: How are you determining that `sleep 1` sleeps for 3 seconds instead?

Comment: No, it sleeps for 1 second after the three files process.

    post
    post
    post
    sleep 1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using the short form of the `for` loop, so that only the `{ curl ... }` command forms the body of the loop; `sleep 1` occurs after the `for` loop. Instead, ensure that the `sleep` command is in the body of the `for` loop with

```
while true
do
   for p in **/*.xml; do
       curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/xml"  -d @"${p}" "https://url/postAPI" > "post_${p}"
       sleep 1
   done
done
```

(You could also put `sleep 1` inside the `{...}` construct that forms the body of the short-form `for` loop, but I recommend avoiding that form except for quick, one-off loops in interactive shells.)

Comment: This does it! I should have seen that before!

Comment: Now Say I want to change it from a while to a script that counts occurrences. 
`X=${1-20}
for (( N=1; N<=X; N++ )); do`

This continues the loop forever.

Comment: It shouldn't. Please open a new question with the relevant details and expected behavior.